# Read file name from a list, find its count and redirect both file name and count to another file in windows cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a beginner in windows scripting and finding it difficult to achieve the below scenario. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

I have an input file with list of file name 
eg : `InputFileName.txt`

```
E:\ABC\File*.csv
E:\ABC\CDF\list.txt
```

( ie files can be present in any directory and also file names need not be accurate. It can have wildcards, so that the matched file needs to be picked)

Steps:

I need to get the count of each individual file listed in InputFileName.txt and write the file name in list,actual file name and its count to another file excluding blank line (or even to table).

Output should look like

```
E:\ABC\File*.csv,E:\ABC\File20191008.csv,200
E:\ABC\CDF\list.txt,E:\ABC\CDF\list.txt,300
```

Code I have just write the count to another file.Tried multiple things but not able to get the first 2 fields I need.

Code :

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%A in ( 'type E:\dir1\InputFileName.txt) do (
findstr /R . %%A | find /c /v "" >>E:\dir1\OutputFileName.txt)
```

Comment: From your example, I'm not sure what count you want. You have 300 File20191008.csv's or does your File20191008.csv contain 300 lines?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers the code OP posted attempts to take each line in the input file, then recursively search for the file and output the number of times the file is found in the directories. So OP is looking for number of files found from a list of files.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - thanks, that was my assumption but my cmd-fu is not strong enough. What would OP then expect when there are multiple files matching the wildcard? `File*.csv` finds `File20191008.csv` but also `Filexxx.csv`. I assume OP expects two lines in this case with each line containing the count of that unique filename.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The wildcard search will actually just do that for each of the given files. So let's assume we have 3 files `E:\file1.txt` `E:\file2.txt` and `file3.txt` if we do `dir /b /s "file*.txt | find /c /v ""` it will `dir` all 3 files and bring back a result  of `3`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers So yes, if the OP expected it to return 1,1,1 for each of the different files, this will not work as he/she expected :)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers..ans to ur first qn: the File20191008 contain 300 lines in it.Also,I am not looking for number of files in the directory, instead the count of lines present in each file present in the filelist.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard : yes , you r correct, File*.csv finds File20191008.csv but also Filexxx.csv. But in my case there would be only one file in the directory which satisfies the condition ie either File20191008.csv or Filexxx.csv, not both. In actual scenario, the postfix of file depends on the day I receive the file, which can be any day. So I am trying for a solution  which is reusable

Comment: @divya but that is exactly what Lieven and I have been discussing. The solution I posted below will return the result of the files, but it will not have independent results for wildcards as the `find /c` will only return the result of the number of files in the single search. so for `file1` `file2` `file3` it will return `3`

Comment: Let me work on something.

Comment: If Powershell is an option, following might get your started `gc e:\dir1\InputfileName.txt -pv currentline | % { gci $_ -Recurse | % {[PSCustomObject]@{input = $currentline; name = $_.name}}} | group input, name -noe | select name, count`

Comment: Please test the answer I posted below and see if the result is what you wanted.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank a lot :) this is the closest result got so far. But am getting the count at the beginning of ouput file and as next line  "E:\dir1s\file1.txt,file1.txt,%I " (ie  getting %%I in output )

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, this seems to be what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type E:\dir1\InputFileName.txt') do (
 for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s "%%a"') do (
    set "name=%%~nxf"
    if not "!oldname!"=="!name!" (
    set "oldname=!name!"
    for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s "%%~nxf" ^|find /c /v ""') do (
    echo %%a,%%~nxf,%%i >>E:\dir1\OutputFileName.txt
   )
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: 2
4
E:\dir1\file1.txt,file1.txt,%I 
E:\dir1\file2.txt,file2.txt,%I 
This is the output i received for the above code

Comment: Please copy from the answer again and try try again, my browser auto capitalized `I` when I copied it in here and fixed it now.

Comment: Now the code is just giving 1 as count for all the file. Also only 2 fields as output where I want 3. Only the original file name and count is coming in output.

Comment: It will only give 1 if the file is only found once.

Comment: Thank a  lot Gerhard...I have been looking for hours to get the solution and you made it possible. I had to change the last for loop as for /f %%i in ('findstr /R . "%%~nxf"^|find /c /v ""') to get the final output though. Thanks again:)

Comment: Ok. Glad you got sorted

Comment: @divya - if this answers your question, you can mark it so by checking the checkmark.